# How to mock a powershell function with mandatory parameters in pester

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, pester

Here is my code:
**Testcase.ps1**

```
function Verify_AuthenticodeSignature{
Param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   [string]$PSFilePath
)
    Write-Host $PSFilePath
    if (-Not (Test-Path $PSFilePath)){
        echo "file does not exist"
        exit 1
    }

    $Status=(Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath $PSFilePath).Status
    if($Status -ne "Valid"){
        echo "Script is not signed"
    } 
}
Verify_AuthenticodeSignature
```

**Testcase.Tests.ps1:**

```
$here = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$sut = (Split-Path -Leaf $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -replace '\.Tests\.', '.'
. "$here\$sut"

Describe "Testing" {

    It "Test Path"{
       Mock Test-Path{$false}
       Mock echo{}

       Verify_AuthenticodeSignature

       Assert-MockCalled echo -Times 1
       #Verify_AuthenticodeSignature -PSFilePath 'D:\abc\xyz.ps1' |should be "file does not exist"
    }       



    It "Authentication"{
        Mock Get-AuthenticodeSignature{ return "valid" }
        Mock echo{}

        Verify_AuthenticodeSignature

        Assert-MockCalled Get-AuthenticodeSignature -Times 1
        Assert-MockCalled echo -Times 1
    }

    }
```

Here I want to mock a powershell function with mandatory parameters in such a way that it doesn't ask for $PSFilePath variable value from user but check the mock function using any dummy value. 
Whenever i am running **Testcase.Tests.ps1** it is prompting for $PSFilePath value and running the source powershell script(**Testcase.ps1**)
I am stuck on this , any suggestion would be of great help.

Comment: Short answer: You can't.  Re-write your test for that case (look at `TestDrive:\ `)

Comment: As an aside: it's a very bad practice to outright exit your script from a function, that should be the job of the controller, not the tool.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary file at `TestDrive:`

```
Describe 'Describing test' {

    it 'dummy test fail' {
         Test-Path TestDrive:\Test.log | Should Be $True 
    }

    it 'dummy test pass' {
        'some file' | Out-File TestDrive:\Test.log
         Test-Path TestDrive:\Test.log | Should Be $True 
    }
}
```